# Disable background color changes but enable text color change on UITableViewCell highlighting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'd like to make a UITableViewCell text color to change when it is selected, but only that. I would like to disable the background highlight in the cell. I saw solutions like:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

But this also disables the text color change. Is the kind of behaviour that I'd like to have achievable in a simple way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, do :

Step 1. Set your selection style as default.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
```

Step 2. Set an empty view as your background view

```
UIView *view = [UIView new] ;
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:view];
```

Step 3. Set text color you want, say

```
[[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[[cell textLabel] setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Yes this is it, exactly as I wanted. It produces some weired behavious with separators, but I think I'll manage.

Comment: Add your custom separator..!! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In your custom tableview cell class override `setSelected` method and based on the selection state update text color accordingly.

Ex:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected) {
        [self.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    } else {
        [self.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` disable default cell selection

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor graycColor];
Cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

try this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: This only changes the textLabel background to black, and does nothing with the selection frame.

Comment: -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblStatusUI.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenSeaColor];

Answer (score 0):

You should try using -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

you should then be able to target the text in cell (depending on how it's set up, and if the label is a property of the cell)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 / iOS 11.2 / Xcode 9.2:**

Overriding **setSelected** is the answer.

If you want the default behavior PLUS some other changes, then leave **selectionStyle** alone, or set it to **.default**:

```
selectionStyle = .default
```

If you want all custom behavior, set it to **.none**:

```
selectionStyle = .none
```

Either way -- even if you set it to **.none**, your overridden **setSelected** will still get called.  For example:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if selected {
        textLabel.textColor = orange
    } else {
        textLabel.textColor = black
    }
}
```